# How would I write a test for a database system such as Redis?

Tags: learning, tdd

So i'm looking into databases and I want to use Redis, but I would like to know how I would go about writing tests for a database such as this before starting with it.

Answer (score 1):

You start by determining what functionality you expect from it (saving value, retrieve it later, etc) and writing tests for it. It is not different that would be writing tests for any other API.

Comment: This API is a little more complicated than "any other API".  See https://aphyr.com/posts/283-call-me-maybe-redis for example.